# Java receive messages from Python server - socket

Tags: java, python, sockets

I try to receive messages from python with socket. My client is code in java.

I wrote code to try get all data that sent from python (just to understand how it works), but I don't get anything.
my code:

Python server:

```
import socket, time

HOST = '10.0.0.2'
PORT = 12345

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
server.listen()
client, address = server.accept()

print('Connected by', address)

while True:
    client.send(b"Hello Java")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

My java code:

```
        try {

            socket = new Socket("10.0.0.2", 12345); // Connect to server

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()); // Get output
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); // Get the input

            while (true) {

                System.out.println(in.readLine()); // It does not print anything
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**How can I receive messages from python?**